# Join/merge dataframes and preserve the row-order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work in `python` and `pandas`.

Let's suppose that I have the following two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2` **(INPUT)**:

```
# df1
    A   B   C
0   2   8   6
1   5   2   5
2   3   4   9
3   5   1   1

# df2
    A   B   C
0   2   7   NaN
1   5   1   NaN
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

I want to process it to join/merge them to get a new dataframe which looks like that **(EXPECTED OUTPUT)**:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   7   NaN
1   5   1   1
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

So basically it is a right-merge/join but with preserving the order of the original right dataframe.

However, if I do this:

```
df_2 = df_1.merge(df_2[['A', 'B']], on=['A', 'B'], how='right')
```

then I get this:

```
    A   B   C
0   5   1   1.0
1   2   7   NaN
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

So I get the right rows joined/merged but the output dataframe does not have the same row-order as the original right dataframe.

**How can I do the join/merge and preserve the row-order too?**

The code to create the original dataframes is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_1 = [[2, 5, 3, 5], [8, 2, 4, 1], [6, 5, 9, 1]]
data_1 = np.array(data_1).T
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, columns=columns)

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_2 = [[2, 5, 3, 5], [7, 1, 3, 0], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]
data_2 = np.array(data_2).T
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, columns=columns)
```

---

*I think that by using either `.join()` or `.update()` I could get what I want but to start with I am quite surprised that `.merge()` does not do this very simple thing too.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way is:

```
df_2=df_2.set_index(['A','B'])

temp = df_1.set_index(['A','B'])

df_2.update(temp)

df_2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

As I discuss above with @jezrael above and if I am not missing something, if you do not need both the columns `C` from the original dataframes and you need only the column `C` with the matching values then `.update()` is the quickest way since you do not have to drop the columns that you do not need.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is bug.

Possible solution with left join:

```
df_2 = df_2.merge(df_1, on=['A', 'B'], how='left', suffixes=('_','')).drop('C_', axis=1)
print (df_2)
     A    B    C
0  2.0  7.0  NaN
1  5.0  1.0  1.0
2  3.0  3.0  NaN
3  5.0  0.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (upvote). Yes it looks like a bug to me or like a big omission. By the way, how do you find my answer below?

Comment: You need replace missing values in column `C` by column `C` from another DaatFrame?

Comment: So you mean that my code replaces NAs with other NAs? (which is obviously redundant)

Comment: No, I think NaNs should be replaced by non NaNs values - if need this, then update is good solution.

Comment: NAs should not be replaced by anything and they should be remain NAs unless there is a matching with a row from the other dataframe. This is why I am talking about a joining/merging. Did I answer your question? (Sorry but I do not understand your question exactly).

Comment: Or you mean that your personal opinion is that NAs should be replaced by proper values because this is the good practice with working with dataframes etc?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - All depends what need, I think both solutions are good. Merge is better if need both columns from left and right DataFrames in final DataFrame separately and update is beeter if need replace same columns from one df by another one.

Comment: Ok, Also, my question is which between our solutions is more efficient in terms of speed? If yours is better then I will choose yours.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - I cannot says it, because it depends of many things - number of matched values, number of rows in one and another DataFrames... So the best test both solutions and choose after testing.

Comment: and yes I liked `.update` more than `.join` (I can do the same with the latter) because I do not have to drop the columns which I do not need since I do not need both the columns `C` from the original dataframes.

Comment: Ya, it is different functions for different usecases... ;)

Comment: So if I have many columns to match (by row) then your `.drop('C_', axis=1)` statement will be pretty big (unless I am missing sth) and perhaps a bit compicated? Hence perhaps if sb does not need the original columns `C` `.update()` must be quicker. (I do not want to trigger a debate - I am just basically asking you since you are much more experienced than me in `pandas`).

Answer (score 0):

You can play with index between the both dataframe

```
print(df)
#    A  B    C
# 0  5  1  1.0
# 1  2  7  NaN
# 2  3  3  NaN
# 3  5  0  NaN

df = df.set_index('B')
df = df.reindex(index=df_2['B'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[['A', 'B', 'C']]

print(df)
#    A    B    C
# 0  2  7.0  NaN
# 1  5  1.0  1.0
# 2  3  3.0  NaN
# 3  5  0.0  NaN
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576800/how-to-sort-dataframe-based-on-a-column-in-another-dataframe-in-pandas?rq=1)