# Drop rows and sort one dataframe according to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have two pandas data frames (`df1` and `df2`):

```py
# df1
  ID  COL
   1    A
   2    F
   2    A
   3    A
   3    S
   3    D
   4    D

# df2
  ID  VAL
   1    1
   2    0
   3    0
   3    1
   4    0
```

My goal is to append the corresponding `val` from `df2` to each `ID` in `df1`. However, the relationship is not one-to-one (this is my client's fault and there's nothing I can do about this). To solve this problem, I want to sort `df1` by `df2['ID']` such that `df1['ID']` is identical to `df2['ID']`.

So basically, for any row `i` in 0 to `len(df2)`:

- if `df1.loc[i, 'ID'] == df2.loc[i, 'ID']` then keep row `i` in `df1`.
- if `df1.loc[i, 'ID'] != df2.loc[i, 'ID']` then drop row `i` from `df1` and repeat.

The desired result is:

```py
  ID  COL
   1    A
   2    F
   3    A
   3    S
   4    D
```

This way, I can use `pandas.concat([df1, df2['ID']], axis=0)` to assign `df2[VAL]` to `df1`.

Is there a standardized way to do this? Does `pandas.merge()` have a method for doing this?

Before this gets voted as a duplicate, please realize that `len(df1) != len(df2)`, so [threads like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576800/how-to-sort-dataframe-based-on-a-column-in-another-dataframe-in-pandas) are not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with merge on both `ID` and the order within each `ID`:

```
(df1.assign(idx=df1.groupby('ID').cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(idx=df2.groupby('ID').cumcount()),
           on=['ID','idx'],
           suffixes=['','_drop'])
    [df1.columns]
)
```

Output:

```
   ID COL
0   1   A
1   2   F
2   3   A
3   3   S
4   4   D
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can see of getting the result you want is:

```py
# Add a count for each repetition of the ids to temporary frames
x = df1.assign(id_counter=df1.groupby('ID').cumcount())
y = df2.assign(id_counter=df2.groupby('ID').cumcount())

# Merge using the ID and the repetition counter
df1 = pd.merge(x, y, how='right', on=['ID', 'id_counter']).drop('id_counter', axis=1)
```

Which would produce this output:

```
    ID  COL VAL
0   1   A   1
1   2   F   0
2   3   A   0
3   3   S   1
4   4   D   0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston It is quite similar, the distinction is the extra column of the output, which was the next step that was required at the end of the original question.